# PostGIS sequence in QGIS not working

Tags: postgis, qgis-2

I have a Multipolygon-Layer stored in a PostgreSQL/PostGIS database.
The primary key field 'gid' is SERIAL.
When trying to add a new polygon in QGIS (LYON 2.12.1 on OSX El Capitan), the attributes form shows me:

`nextval('test_gid_seq'::regclass)` for the gid field (which is the correct sequence to autoincrement the field).

When I try to save the edits, I always get an error:

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "test_pkey"
    DETAIL:  Key (gid)=(1) already exists.
```

This is strange, since the actual value in the sequence is 114. Why does QGIS tries to use 1?
Is this a bug in QGIS? Or does anybody know how to avoid these problems?

Comment: Sounds like it isn't sending the full field list. It is easy to simulate this error:  `create table test (id serial primary key, val int); insert into test values (1);insert into test values (1);` where the second insert fails with `ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "test_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.` This, of course, is because there is no explicit field list. If the insert was instead `insert into test (val) values (1);` then it works. I'm sure you know this, but I can't see any other way that this error could arise.

Comment: Are you sure that the actual value is 114? You can check by running SELECT nextval('test_gid_seq'::regclass) directly in postgres.

Comment: Yes, the value is correct.

Comment: gid integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval ('test_gid_seq'::regclass),

Answer (score -1):

Run this:

```
SELECT setval('test_gid_seq', (SELECT MAX(gid) FROM your_table)+1);
```

Comment: No. Dont do that. Bad answer. It fails if you have multiple accesses, (For instance two transactions trying to write at the same time). Postgres has a SERIAL type that can take care of this by generating a new series key when its asked for, which means its 'thread safe' so to speak. 

Its an old MYSQL technique and they stopped using that over there a long time ago for good reasons.